# css animation how to get the ball to bounce

Tags: css, animation

Im learning about CSS animation at the moment, Im wondering how to smoothly bounce the ball up and then back down again, at the moment its smoothly going up but resets once it gets to the top and starts again (as oppose to falling down again)

```
.football {
 background-image:url('football.png');
 height:45px;
 width:45px;
 top:100%;
 left:40%;
 position:absolute;
 animation:football_up_down 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes football_up_down {  
 100% { transform:rotate(360deg); top:30%;  } 
 0% { transform:rotate(180deg); top:100%} 

}
```

Comment: animation-direction: alternate;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they already said in comments you could add `animation-direction: alternate`.

But you could also add a 50% point as the peak point, and then a 100% point copying 0%. Summing the rotation angles of the previous keyframes adds a more realistic effect on the repetition. i.e.:

```
@keyframes football_up_down {  
  0% { transform:rotate(180deg); top:100% } 
  50% { transform:rotate(360deg); top:30%; } 
  100% { transform:rotate(540deg); top:100% } 
}
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/w2mH8/

Comment: would be more good if you add `animation-direction: alternate` in CSS. Then your answer will be acceptable.

Comment: What do you mean? I start by pointing he could use that, but in that case he animation would reverse, and it's more realistic if the ball keeps rolling in the same direction.

Comment: well first thing your DEMO is not completely working. thats only show the code.. I want to help OP and help other people so people see answer can easily get an answer.

Comment: Oh you're right I don't know what happened with that. I've moved the example to jsfiddle and now the DEMO should work. Thank you.